# If God is one why is there isolation and why God allowed this?

Tags: vedas, gods, christianity

We as Hindus(vedic knowledge) know that god is one and the variety in Hinduism are different representation of god him/her/it self.

Same is the concept of Christianity the holy trinity is one god.Jesus himself claims that "me and father are one and the same" also he claims that "no one gets to father except through him" (my understanding is that he said this in the context where the people of Israel were seeking God but the religion at that time was already corrupt so he points out the message he carries is the only way since bible also claims he is the word itself).

Both Christianity and Hindu concepts are same but divided by the saviour's names , in Christianity we need to be born again through spirit (realize that you have a holy spirit to guide you), similarly in Hinduism we attain eternity by realizing our true nature (born again - changing our ways of thinking by realizing our soul and paramathma).

There are many other places where i find similarities. Some verses are read out of context and gives different meaning and misleads many.

Every thing sounds similar but different saviour,s even if they are reincarnation of one God without God's motive nothing happens so why there is division in religions are we prepared for something?

Comment: very good question. The different sects have different opinions on the matter. The dualists and related sects would say 'due to the karma of the person, he is born as a Christian where he is fed with wrong knowledge :P'. The non-dualists - Advaitins - say that the different religions such as Christianity, Buddhism, Hinduism, etc are simply various ways to reach the same God. For example, you need to get to dubai. You can go via frankfurt, paris or spain. it doesnt' matter where your layover is, as long as you get to the destination. Similarly with religion all religions->GOD. All the best sir!

Comment: the isolation is not about god, the isolation is about the way of living the same life, and it doesn't matters to him, how the world goes, he;s neutral to everything.

Comment: Thanks !! For ur points to add more on this even I feel it's all about personal revelation which all religions point to. Those who really seek for God will eventually understand this point and come out of the box that every religion creates.

Comment: @Sai Is that just a view of modern Advaitins or did even Adi Shankaracharya have a similar view of Mleccha religions?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan As far as I can remember the concept of 'religion' is not around during Adi Shankaracharya's time. It is a much more modern notion. But different religions leading to God was mainly propagated by the modern day saints, because in this day and age, religious strife is more. There is a greater need for this unity. This is my guess and I would have to do more research to find out. Thanks

Comment: @Sai Adi Shankaracharya didn't live that long ago.  There was plenty of contact with people from other religions like the Greeks and the like.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes but I mean to say that while there were different beliefs, just as there were different beliefs even in Hinduism. But I don't think the idea of 'You belong to this religion and I belong to this religion' or 'Your religion decides whether or not you attain Moksha' and the like were there. These were modern notions.

Comment: This is a very good question.It clearly shows that you have read and understood the concepts, of atleast, more than two religions.To satisfy, the intellect, it is mentioned that there is an "unmanifest"/ un-decipherable  side to God.Returning back to why divisions/ isolation etc- this is related to "free will".A christian is free to worship a Hindu God and a Hindu is free to worship a Christian God , and likewise many other religions and many other Gods.And ultimately it may help in reaching the same goal- which is mentioned in your question.